# External SSD not recognized after installing webmin

Tags: pi-3b+, hard-drive

I have an SSD connected to my rpi3 using the Element14 Pi Desktop kit.  This hardware configuration has been working; this issue started after re-imaging the SD card with Raspbian Stretch.

The SSD is recognized and mapped to /dev/sda (and sometimes auto-mounts under /media/pi), but after installing Webmin, it no longer appears, even under `lsblk`.  What is causing the rpi to not even see the drive?

```
pi@diskpi:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.941_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package webmin.
(Reading database ... 138786 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack webmin_1.941_all.deb ...
Unpacking webmin (1.941) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of webmin:
 webmin depends on libnet-ssleay-perl; however:
  Package libnet-ssleay-perl is not installed.
 webmin depends on libauthen-pam-perl; however:
  Package libauthen-pam-perl is not installed.
 webmin depends on libio-pty-perl; however:
  Package libio-pty-perl is not installed.
 webmin depends on apt-show-versions; however:
  Package apt-show-versions is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package webmin (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u12) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 webmin
pi@diskpi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libipopt1v5 libmumps-seq-4.10.0 libraw15
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl perl-openssl-defaults
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl perl-openssl-defaults
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 435 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,662 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf perl-openssl-defaults armhf 3 [6,782 B]
Get:2 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libnet-ssleay-perl armhf 1.80-1 [270 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libauthen-pam-perl armhf 0.16-3+b3 [25.9 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libio-pty-perl armhf 1:1.08-1.1+b2 [33.0 kB]
Get:5 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf libapt-pkg-perl armhf 0.1.32 [64.8 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf apt-show-versions all 0.22.7 [34.3 kB]
Fetched 435 kB in 3s (137 kB/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package perl-openssl-defaults:armhf.
(Reading database ... 167469 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-perl-openssl-defaults_3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking perl-openssl-defaults:armhf (3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet-ssleay-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnet-ssleay-perl_1.80-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libnet-ssleay-perl (1.80-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libauthen-pam-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libauthen-pam-perl_0.16-3+b3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libauthen-pam-perl (0.16-3+b3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-pty-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libio-pty-perl_1%3a1.08-1.1+b2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libio-pty-perl (1:1.08-1.1+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapt-pkg-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libapt-pkg-perl_0.1.32_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-pkg-perl (0.1.32) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apt-show-versions.
Preparing to unpack .../5-apt-show-versions_0.22.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-show-versions (0.22.7) ...
Setting up libauthen-pam-perl (0.16-3+b3) ...
Setting up libapt-pkg-perl (0.1.32) ...
Setting up apt-show-versions (0.22.7) ...
** initializing cache. This may take a while **
Setting up libio-pty-perl (1:1.08-1.1+b2) ...
Setting up perl-openssl-defaults:armhf (3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libnet-ssleay-perl (1.80-1) ...
Setting up webmin (1.941) ...
Webmin install complete. You can now login to https://diskpi:10000/
as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo
to run commands as root.
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u12) ...
```

---

*Update*:
I initially re-imaged the sd card with Buster, which is when the problem above started.  So I tried Stretch, same thing, so I tried Jessie (which seems to be the version Element14 used to test) and it wouldn't even boot.  It hung on the "color gradient" boot screen, with the undervolt icon blinking.  I then went back to my original sd card with Buster and the SSD is back.

*(note: I only ever saw the undervolt icon with Jessie)*

---

*Update*:
After returning to my original sd card with Buster, the drive appeared and would mount, but an `ls` hung and then gave an error:
`ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`

I started to suspect insufficient power (despite Element14's assertion that a 2.5A power supply was sufficient to power the rpi+SSD), so I bought a new one that provided up to 3.5A (I have yet to check with my Kill-a-Watt).  It worked for a while, but now is giving me the same I/O errors as before.

I rebooted the pi and and drive mounted correctly, but after about 10 hours, `dmesg` showed:

```
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=0x00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 0c e0 00 00 00 f0 00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:11 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 843776
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=0x00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 0c e0 f0 00 00 10 00
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 844016
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 105121792
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 13139968, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 843776
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 105121792
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 13139968, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 50333960
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572963: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572961: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572956: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572967: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572960: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572955: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572951: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572950: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1455: inode #131073: comm bash: reading directory lblock 0
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572965: block 6291494: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4708: inode #1572952: block 6291493: comm ldconfig: unable to read itable block
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 15761408, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 15761408, lost sync page write
[Fri Apr 17 18:45:42 2020] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
```

Comment: This is a fresh install, so I am able to start with a fresh image if anyone has suggestions to try.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you really suspect webmin to be a root cause or not? That is, does the SSD work again when you flash a fresh image?